# Creating a provisioning profile and signing it

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode9

When trying to archive, Xcode throws lots of errors.

> Failed to create provisioning profile.

It also complains about no registered devices:

> There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

And some more errors related to provisioning profiles:

> No profiles for 'com.Tom-s-Creations.Bouncy-Heavens' were found
>
> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles
>   matching 'com.Tom-s-Creations.Bouncy-Heavens'.

I'm new to Xcode code signing and would like some help. How would I go about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First solution:

You have to create a profile on the apple developer website.

https://developer.apple.com

There you can you also register devices for the development.

You can set the provisioning profile in Xcode on the signing area below the team.

Second Solution:

You can also enable automatic signing in the signing area. Selet "your name" (Personal Team)

So no signing is required. This has the disadvantage that you can only use the simulator. If you need real hardware for development and testing you have to sign.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more info on "There you can you also register devices for the development." I can't findi t.

Comment: Go to the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section and create a provisioning profile. But you need it only for distribution. If you in the developing phase make the fast second solution

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to work by plugging my iphone in once and havibg it registered to my account. Then i could unplug it and automatic signing etc worked. Didn’t need to manually register a provisioning profile.